# Intellisense broken in 64 bit Windows when using mixed-mode (i.e. managed C++) assemblies

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, intellisense, managed-c++

This is annoying more than anything, but I have no working Intellisense when I use any of my custom web controls in .aspx/.ascx pages. Intellisense in standard `<asp:...>` controls are fine, as it is in all code-behind files etc.

I'm pretty sure this is caused by Visual Studio attempting to analyse the website's bin folder for custom web controls, and throwing a hissy fit when it gets to one of the DLLs - a (mixed-mode)  64-bit managed C++ assembly (I'm running 64-bit Win 7). It seems that Visual Studio tries to load this assembly, and fails, due to VS being a 32-bit app.

Anyone have any ideas how to work around this? I looked for an option to get VS to ignore the 64-bit assembly (there are no web controls in it - they exist in another standard assembly), but alas, nothing to be found.

Note: this is VS 2010, but I'd imagine this would be a problem in any version.